# Fibration and induced mapping

Tags: algebraic-topology, fibration

I need help in such a problem, suppose it's rather simple one, but I have no skill in a field..
If $p: E\rightarrow  B$ - fibration with a fibre F, then for every locally compact space $X$ an induced mapping $p_*:Map(X,E)\rightarrow Map(X,B)$ is a fibration. Also: $\Omega p:\Omega E\rightarrow\Omega B$ is a fibration.

I'd like to use the following theorem (Borsuk's thm):
$X$ - locally compact, $j:A\rightarrow X$ - Borsuk's pair, then $j^*:Map(X,Y)\rightarrow Map(A,Y)$ - cofibration.

and somehow use the duality of co- and fibrations. Is this a good way to prove it?

Thanks and take care

Comment: You can do it without that theorem, straight from the definition of fibration... Use the adjunction between maps and products/smash products

Comment: And the definition of Serre fibration via the homotopy lifting property